# how to detect empty / null value in list which may contain numeric or string?

Tags: python

I have list containing multiple dictionary objects.  I want to detect when there is no value in a specific key-value pair.  When the value exists it is numeric.  When the value does not exist, it appears to be is an empty string (judging from the Stack Data).

Initially I tried:

```
for dictionary_item in row_list:
    if dictionary_item['targetkey'] == '':
        #do stuff
```

This throws an "unsupported operand type" error when it encounters a number.

The value in the key-value pair may be either a number or an empty string.  What is a good test expression for this scenario?

Comment: What is the full traceback? `unsupported operand type` is not an exception I'd expect from the code posted here.

Comment: From error logging...Traceback info:
  File "C:\Source\Script\FTTB_Loader.py", line 118, in RemoveNonLatLon
    print item['SERIAL_NUMBER'] + " is missing location information."

Error Info:
unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'str'

Comment: @MartijnPieters You are correct.  The error is thrown when trying to print a number without casting (.NET term, sorry) to string.  It looks like the test expression is being evaluated without throwing an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally would use [`isinstance`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#isinstance):

```
if isinstance(dictionary_item['targetkey'], float):
```

This will work even if the number is `0.0`, which evaluates to `False` in Python.

See a demonstration below:

```
>>> bool(0.0)
False
>>> isinstance(0.0, float)
True
>>> isinstance(10.0, float)
True
>>> isinstance('', float)
False
>>>
```

Comment: Judging by the traceback, the OP is using floats.

Comment: Got it.  I changed `int` to `float`.

Comment: I like the idea of putting some type checking in though with the if expression being evaluated correctly (thanks @MartijnPieters) I'm not sure what the best practice would be.

Comment: @iCodez your recommendation fits my scenario perfectly.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it'll work as long as the values in the dictionary don't include zero:

```
if dictionary_item['targetkey']:
    # do stuff
```

The above will check if `dictionary_item['targetkey']` is non-null, non-empty and non-zero. If zero *is* a valid value in the dictionary, then do this:

```
if dictionary_item['targetkey'] or dictionary_item['targetkey'] == 0:
    # do stuff
```

Comment: Also good idea, thanks.  The values will hold latitude, longitude values.  Your suggestion made me realize I need to put in an additional range value check 180 to 180 and -90 to 90).